# Solving the equation $y'^2-2xy'+2y-x^2=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation:
$$y'^2-2xy'+2y-x^2=0$$

---

First, I tried to solve it w.r.t $y'$:
$$y' = \frac{2x \pm \sqrt{4x^2 - 4(2y-x^2)}}{2} \\[5mm]y' = x\pm\sqrt{2x^2-2y}$$
Now, I don't know how to solve this one. Still I have attempted as follows
$$y'-x = \pm \sqrt{2x^2-2y} \\[5mm] z = y-x^2/2 \implies z' = y'-x \\[5mm] z' = \pm\sqrt{-2z+x^2}$$
Then, I got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'^2-2xy'+2y-x^2=0$$
Change the variable to $v=x^2$:
$$4v(y'^2-y')+2y=v$$
$$y(v)=v  \left( 2 \left(y'-y'^2\right)+\dfrac 12 \right)$$
Is on the form:
$$y=vf(y')$$
This is [D'Alembert differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_equation)
$$y=vf(y')+g(y')$$